# JPA create new entity, how to connect its relationship

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

For example, I have a table "goods", it has a "categoryId" column, which is another "category" table with id and name.

When I create a `goods` entity, I have the `name`, and `categoryId` on hand, I need to query the category entity first, and then call "setCategory" function in the `goods` entity, and save it to database in the end.

That looks not good for me, everytime I create a `goods` entity, I need to query the category entity by its id first, I am wondering is there any easy, high performance way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming category is master data, you may want to cache the categories in the memory. Retrieval of Category Object from the cache will be high performing. `Hibernate` has good caching support e.g. [Second Level Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache), [Query Cache](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-querycache) etc. I would advice you to leverage the same.

[ehcache](http://ehcache.org/documentation/user-guide/hibernate) is another option to use for caching.

Answer (score 0):

The category entities will be [cached](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Cache.html), so unless each "goods" entity refers to a different category, you probably will have acceptable performance.

If you are really worried about it, you can use [EntityManager.getReference](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29) to retrieve a lightweight version of the category entity.

Answer (score 0):

don't do anything unless you have performance issues !!
querying a category by its id and adding to goods is just fine ! don't try to find issues where there are not